# keyboard bug when use UIKeyboardAppearanceDark - Objective C

Tags: objective-c

when I call this code the keyboard become with gray color.
but sometimes the keyboard show like this image , and return to the gray after i switch keyboard.

**update :**

I think its happened after I open alert view and the keyboard was open.

[image]
 [paypalAddressTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];

[image]

Comment: This is not the Apple's bug tracker.